# смайлики в телеграм боте как сделать так что бы они высвечивались

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Смайлики в телеграм боте как сделать так что бы они высвечивались. Пишу код в PyCharm, нашла коды смайликов вставляю , а в телеграм боте не высвечивается пишет как цифровое значение, того же что я и вводила.

Comment: Как вставляете? Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Зачем вставлять коды? Вставляйте смайлики напрямую без всяких кодов 

Answer (score 0):

Возможно какие-то ошибки в кодах смайликов или же телеграм не поддерживает вставку смайликов как тот же ВК (кодом, а-ля html-кодом ☭). Попробуйте попросту скопировать нужный смайлик в PyCharm. Даже если PyCharm его вам не отобразит должным образом, он всё равно передаст нужный код в telegram при отправке сообщений, а телеграм уже воспримет его нормально.

---

Всем добра-бобра